# Error de recuperacion de contraseña Prestashop 1.7

Tags: php, prestashop

Instale prestashop en un sevidor Ubuntu 18 y funciona todo muy bien pero la funcion de recuperar contraseña tiene error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Según [aqui](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/941827-solved-prestashop-17-problem-when-create-account/) y [aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.intl.php), requieres el módulo o extensión php-intl instalado.

Comment: Si lo tengo habilitado. Lo habilite en php.ini e reinicie el apache y sigue igual.

Answer (score 1):

la forma mas sencilla que he encontrado para resolver este problema es hacerlo manualmente, accede a tu archivo `app>config>parameters.php`

```
<?php return array (
  'parameters' => 
  array (
    'database_host' => 'localhost',
    'database_port' => '',
    'database_name' => 'DATABASENAME',
    'database_user' => 'USERDB',
    'database_password' => 'PASSDB',
    'database_prefix' => 'ps_',
    'database_engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'mailer_transport' => 'smtp',
    'mailer_host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'mailer_user' => NULL,
    'mailer_password' => NULL,
    'secret' => 'e1zYAAYXAddKcApWXwuoAguDGB69kssqxIJgO8eZPacdfGgk1QETC',
    'ps_caching' => 'CacheMemcache',
    'ps_cache_enable' => false,
    'ps_creation_date' => '2021-06-14',
    'locale' => 'en-US',
    'use_debug_toolbar' => true,
    'cookie_key' => 'w3Ss5YZi12ihs3dIh7YouetJIkNI6j7FbRd1N...ETC', //esta es la linea de valores que necesitas
    'cookie_iv' => 'y2orrGAJ',
    'new_cookie_key' => 'defetc',
  ),
);
```

Copia la linea de valores `cookie_key` en mi caso `w3Ss5YZi12ihs3dIh7YouetJIkNI6j7FbRd1N...ETC`

*Luego accede a tu administrador de base de datos y

*busca la tabla `ps_employee` en mi caso `ps_` porque en el archivo de configuración tengo como `database_prefix=ps_`

*busca el usuario a que le quieres resetear la contraseña y presiona en EDIT,

*en el campo `passwd` le agregas como **función** `MD5` -> pegas tu `cookie_key` seguido de una contraseña nueva.

en mi caso quedaría `w3Ss5YZi12ihs3dIh7YouetJIkNI6j7FbRd1N...ETCMINUEVACONTRASEñA` en donde la palabra `MINUEVACONTRASEñA` es tu nueva contraseña.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esto ya podrías acceder a tu backoffice haciendo uso de tu nueva contraseña.

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

tienes acceso a la BD?

busca la tabla: **ps_employee**
en el campo: **passwd** escribe: **$P$DjO/RbpP3OtjInoxd1InMWeQZrCIcr.**
esta clave es el cifrado de la palabra: admin123
guarda
y cuando entres al admin de prestashop
Usuario: el correo que tengas configurado
Pass: **admin123**